# Draw a staggered isometric map with python

Tags: python, pygame, staggered-gridview

I am facing some issues while trying to create a staggered isomteric game map with pygame.

So far I can draw a rectangular one but I have no clue on how to rotate it.

Here is the code:

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame

green = (40,255,30)
brown = (40,60,90)

grass = 0
dirt = 1

colours = {
    grass: green,
    dirt: brown,
    }

tilemap = [
        [grass,dirt,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [dirt,grass,dirt,dirt, dirt],
        [grass, grass,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [grass, grass,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [dirt,dirt,dirt,dirt,grass]

        ]

TILESIZE = 50
MAPWIDTH =  5
MAPHEIGHT = 5

pygame.init()
DISPLAYMAP = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        DISPLAYMAP.fill((0, 0, 0))
        for row in range(MAPWIDTH):
            print
            for column in range(MAPHEIGHT):
                color = colours[tilemap[row][column]]
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYMAP, color, (column * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is the result:

[image: rectangular map]

And I would like to have something looking like this:

[image: Expected output]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.transform.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) and [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) to create an isometric [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object for each kind of tile:

```py
isometric_tiles = {}
for key, color in colours.items():
    tile_surf = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    tile_surf.fill(color)
    tile_surf = pygame.transform.rotate(tile_surf, 45)
    isometric_size = tile_surf.get_width()
    tile_surf = pygame.transform.scale(tile_surf, (isometric_size, isometric_size//2))
    isometric_tiles[key] = tile_surf
```

[`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the tiles instead of drawing rectangles:

```py
for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        tile_surf = isometric_tiles[tilemap[row][column]]
        x = (column + (MAPHEIGHT - row)) * isometric_size // 2
        y = 20 + (column + row) * isometric_size // 4 
        DISPLAYMAP.blit(tile_surf, (x, y))
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame

green = (40,255,30)
brown = (40,60,90)

grass = 0
dirt = 1

colours = {
    grass: green,
    dirt: brown,
    }

tilemap = [
        [grass,dirt,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [dirt,grass,dirt,dirt, dirt],
        [grass, grass,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [grass, grass,dirt,dirt, grass],
        [dirt,dirt,dirt,dirt,grass]
]

TILESIZE = 50
MAPWIDTH =  5
MAPHEIGHT = 5

isometric_tiles = {}

for key, color in colours.items():
    tile_surf = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    tile_surf.fill(color)
    tile_surf = pygame.transform.rotate(tile_surf, 45)
    isometric_size = tile_surf.get_width()
    tile_surf = pygame.transform.scale(tile_surf, (isometric_size, isometric_size//2))
    isometric_tiles[key] = tile_surf

pygame.init()
DISPLAYMAP = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE*2,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        DISPLAYMAP.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
            for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
                tile_surf = isometric_tiles[tilemap[row][column]]
                x = (column + (MAPHEIGHT - row)) * isometric_size // 2
                y = 20 + (column + row) * isometric_size // 4 
                DISPLAYMAP.blit(tile_surf, (x, y))
        
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

For the staggered representation you have to change the arrangement of the tiles:

[image]

```py
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        DISPLAYMAP.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
            for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
                tile_surf = isometric_tiles[tilemap[row][column]]
                x = 20 + column * isometric_size + (row % 2) * isometric_size // 2
                y = 20 + row * isometric_size // 4 
                DISPLAYMAP.blit(tile_surf, (x, y))
        
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know now, how can i go from your diamond shape to a staggered shape? So i can have a rectangular map but with the tiles rotated? Thank you again

Comment: @NicolasPeille A staggered shape is just a snippet of a larger map. I think you completely misunderstood the concept of an isometric view. The arrangement of the tiles doesn't change, just the view on them changes.

Comment: @NicolasPeille I've extended the answer.

Comment: Thank you man! Yes you are right, I guess i need to read more on the isometric view concept. Was not clear at all. Thank you anyways !